# Chrome Packaged App: chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry multiple selection

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome Packaged App with a sandboxed section within it.

When a button is clicked in the sandbox, a `postMessage` message is passed up to the main application with a command for opening a file dialog input `(chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry [type="openFile"]`.

Everything works great, but I can't find any solution for enabling multiple selection in the file dialog.

Currently I can only select and choose one file at a time.

Hope there's some attribute I missed out there...

**EDIT:**

Solution - acceptsMultiple: true

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile', acceptsMultiple: true, accepts: accepts}, function(entry) { ... });
```

Comment: I don't think the sandbox part of your question is relevant. It would be easier for people to understand the question if you removed that.

Answer (score 1):

Since Chrome 30 it is possible. Here is an example on how to use it:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile', accepts: extensionFilter , acceptsMultiple: true }, function(theEntry, fileEntries) {

var fileCount = theEntry.length;
console.log("fileCount = " + fileCount );

// use local storage to retain access to this file
chrome.storage.local.set({'chosenFile': chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(theEntry[0])});

for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
    chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(theEntry[i], function(path) {
         console.log( path );
    });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry method works only with a single file. The callback returns a single fileEntry. You might want to star https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159062, which suggests adding multiple-file functionality.